magento 2.4 is there a way to check whether customer is logged in after registration?
in my magento 2.4.4 I have placed two observers, one for intercepting the registration process (customer_register_success) and another one to intercept when the user logs in(customer_login).
What I realized is that upon registration both events get fired, so basically my code is executed twice:

the user lands on the registation page, completes the form, submits the data, the creation of the account is successful so the customer_register_success event is fired
then the user is redirected to their customer account and the customer_login event is fired.

My question is: in the customer_login event, is there a way to know whether the account has just been created? Something like:
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    if($accountHasJustBeenCreated) return;
    // proceed with original code
}


My suggestion to make this problem easier to handle is to create an additional model and this additional model performs the action you see being performed twice

then both observers can call the model rather than doing the same job twice

Now, since you will have a new model in your codebase, you can add a property accountHasJustBeenCreated in this model.
In Magento model are by default shared instance. That means when the first observer will have consumed your model, then the second observer will also trigger the method but this time the property will have been set and therefore the processing won't be happening anymore
